# How to implement badges in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to display a badge on my angular "ion-tab". I have one "tabs.html" file where my tabs code is written.

```
<!-- some code -->
  <ion-tab  icon-off="notificationIconDisabled" icon-on="notificationIconEnabled"  href="#/tab/newjob" badge="{{newJobsCount}}" badge-style="badge-assertive">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-newjob"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
<!-- some code -->
```

I have another files as tab-setting.html, tab-myjobs.html and tab-newjobs.html. "myjobs.html" and "tab-newjobs.html" are using controller "jobCtrl.js". Now as I am trying to set badge through "jobCtrl.js" as follows,

```
$scope.newJobsCount = $scope.jobList.length;
```

I am unable to do it, and I am getting following error in browser for badge

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2
>   of the expression [{{newJobsCount}}] starting at [{newJobsCount}}].

can anybody please help me with an example how to implement badges in angular js??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using [`iconic`](http://ionicframework.com/)?

Comment: yes...i am using ionic.

Comment: @Mr. Noddy: badge="{{newJobsCount}}" must be changed to badge="newJobsCount"

Comment: i tried using same... but its not working... maybe i have done some small mistake somewhere.....

Answer (score 2):

Have you already seen these posts and samples?

http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/vLRYvb

[Ionic tabs Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407264/ionic-tabs-badge)

http://play.ionic.io/app/52586f24b84d

http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/knyLj/

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/badge-icons-in-tabs/626/10

However use [badge](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTab/) attribute, for example:

```
<ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios7-information" href="#/tab/about"  badge="data.badgeCount" badge-style="badge-assertive" ng-controller="AboutCtrl" >...</ion-tab>
```

PS: avoid to use primitives as model (badge attribute here is bound to data.badgeCount, not only badgeCount)

Comment: in particular the 3rd is suitable for your needs. Pay attention to the sintax: `badge="data.badgeCount"` not `badge="{{data.badgeCount}}"`